# What is the difference between "How precious is it?" and "How much is it precious?"

Tags: meaning, expressions

I would appreciate if you help....

Comment: Thank you for your considerate answer.  What I want to know is whether "How much + Be-Verb + subject + Adjective?" is possible or not. Is this structure possible?

Comment: In most cases, no. See the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*How precious is it?* is very unlikely in English, for in speaking of something as *precious* we are usually assigning it an emotive rather than a quantifiable value. Using *precious* this way reminds me irresistibly of Gollum.

What you probably mean is

> How **valuable** is it?

*How much is it precious?* is even more unlikely; the only circumstance under which I can imagine it occurring is with a comma after *it* and *precious* employed as an endearment:

> How much is it, precious? If it's not too expensive, I'll buy it for you.

*How much is it __?* asks for a quantity or amount; its complements are expressions which take quantities or amounts (either specific or indefinite like *much*, *a lot*, and the like) as their own complements:

> How much is it worth? —Eh, it's not worth very much.
>   How much is it selling for? —It's selling for a thousand dollars.
>   How much is it per pound? —Oh, let's say it's seven bucks. But I'll give you two pounds for eleven bucks.

Comment: I agree with your response. However, within a comparative context, "how precious is it?" would be a viable question.